# Google Sign in getting Developer_error sometimes and others working

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

Mostly as said in the title, sometimes when I enter my app the Google sign-in is returning an error 10, `Developer_error`, and others it enters perfectly good. This error means:

> Google Play services were unable to find a matching client from the
>   console based on your SHA1 and package name

I'm using the 'Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in)', How can it work sometimes and sometimes not?